# CPLEX Python API installment on Mac big sur(M1) CpoException problem

Tags: optimization, cplex

I just install Cplex on my mac(m1). When I run any example code, it shows this error.

File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.9/site- packages/docplex/cp/solver/solver_local.py", line 120, in **init**
raise CpoException("Executable file '{}' does not exists".format(xfile))

CpoException: Executable file 'cpoptimizer' does not exists.

What's the main issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved:

Just change this line 
msol = mdl.solve(TimeLimit=10) to

msol = mdl.solve(TimeLimit=10, execfile='/Applications/CPLEX_Studio221/cpoptimizer/bin/x86-64_osx/cpoptimizer')